# Como puedo mostrar el valor que pone el usuario al entrar a la pagina en una etiqueta a de html

Tags: javascript, html

```
function Bienvenida() {
  let Nombre = prompt("Ingrese su nombre");
  document.write("<a href='#'>" + Nombre + "</a>")
}
```

```
<a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">
  <script>
    Bienvenida()
  </script>
</a>
```

Quiero que cuando el usuario ingrese a la página y ponga su nombre, el nombre que escribió aparezca en esa etiqueta `<a>` que está en el navbar, pero no logro que funcione.

Comment: A menos que trabajes en caché, ese nombre se va a perder al recargar la página o cerrar el navegador, consideraste eso?

Comment: No lo considere la verdad, no tenia ni idea

Answer (score 2):

Debes usar [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) si quieres asegurar la permanencia de los datos aunque se recargue y/o cierre la página o el navegador.

```html
<a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#" id="NombreLink"></a>
```

```js
addEventListener("load", () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("nombre") !== null) {
    // Items no existentes en localStorage dan null
    NombreLink.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("nombre");
    return;
    // Return para parar la ejecución de la función
  }
  // Si no se halló, preguntar y guardar
    const n = prompt("Ingresa tu nombre");
  localStorage.setItem("nombre", n);
  NombreLink.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("nombre");
});
```

[Ejemplo reproducible en JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/863yc701/)

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada, considera lo que dice Jheyman:

> A menos que trabajes en caché, ese nombre se va a perder al recargar la página o cerrar el navegador

Ahora, respondiendo tal cual lo que quieres, podríamos hacer lo siguiente:
Primero, a tu etiqueta `<a>` le damos un ID para reconocerlo en javascript:

```
<!--Le agregamos un ID a tu etiqueta <a>-->
<a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#" id="NombreLink"></a>
```

Después, con el ID, hacemos el siguiente script, que hace lo que quieres, utilizando `innerHTML` que, básicamente, incrusta dentro de un elemento lo que tu le mandes. En este caso, lo que ingresen en tu `prompt`. También añadimos un evento que llamará a `Bienvenida();` cuando la página se cargue completamente.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Bienvenida() {
            let Nombre = prompt("Ingrese su nombre");
            //obtenemos el elementos por el ID y pasamos el texto que ingresó el usuario
            document.getElementById("NombreLink").innerHTML=Nombre;
        }
        //este método se corre cuando la página se terminó de cargar. aquí llamamos el método Bienvenida();
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            Bienvenida();
        });
    </script>
```

y reitero lo de Jheyman, si recargas la página, cierras el explorador, o vas a otra página del mismo sitio, ese dato se pierde.

¡Saludos! :D

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me funciono, saludos!